# Specifying Cocoapod source files via target membership instead of directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoapods

Unless I've diagnosed my problem incorrectly, it seems to me that Cocoapods requires that you specify source files as either global with `s.source_files =` or as platform-specific with `s.ios.source_files =` (or whatever platform).

Is there no way to just specify all the source files together (global and platform-specific), while just letting their target/platform settings within Xcode dictate what should be built for a given platform?

I don't want to have to separate my source files into directories like `common/`, `iOS/`, and `macOS/` **and also** set the appropriate target memberships.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
s.source_files = 'YOUR_PROJECT/*'
```

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem - all the files in that directory are included as source files for *every platform*, regardless of what targets they belong to (and thus, what platforms).